# Python - choice order item in graph

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I would like to know how to order items in a table.
I use age group and when I make table with it, it's automatically class in Ascending values. I want to class the value by the order of age group.

I make :

```
effectifs = data["TR_AGE"].value_counts(dropna=False)
modalites = effectifs.index
tabage = pd.DataFrame(modalites, columns = ["TR_AGE"])
tabage["Effectif"] = effectifs.values
tabage["Fréquence %"] = round((tabage["Effectif"] / len(data) )*100, 2) 

tabage

out[]

    TR_AGE              Effectif    Fréquence %
0   Entre 45 et 49 ans  194         14.51
1   Entre 50 et 54 ans  172         12.86
2   Entre 40 et 44 ans  163         12.19
3   Entre 55 et 59 ans  159         11.89
4   Entre 60 et 64 ans  144         10.77
5   Entre 35 et 39 ans  117         8.75
6   Entre 65 et 69 ans  111         8.30
7   Entre 30 et 34 ans  75          5.61
8   Entre 70 et 74 ans  66          4.94
9   Entre 25 et 29 ans  56          4.19
10  Moins de 25 ans     51          3.81
11  75 ans ou plus      29          2.17
```

and I would like this :

```
AGE GROUP                 Effectif      %
Moins de 25 ans           51            3.81
Entre 25 et 29 ans        56            4.19
Entre 30 et 34 ans        75            5.61
...                       ...           ...
```

I tried to use parameter "order" but it's not working...

Thank you for advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function with regex and df.apply to create a minimum age column in the dataframe, then sort using that. Sorting the strings will not work:

```
def age_sort(x):
    if 'Moins' in x:
        return 0
    elif 'plus' in x:
        return 200
    else:
        min_age = int(re.search('\d+', x).group())
        return min_age


tabage['min_age'] = df.apply(lambda x: age_sort(x['TR_AGE']), axis=1)

tabage = tabage.sort_values('min_age')
```